# Dropdown master page didn't work after change page

Tags: c#, asp.net, drop-down-menu, master-pages, nav

Didn't work dropdownlist Risk Content in master page after change page to the setting page. The dropdown just work after go back to home page again

*MasterPage.master*

```html
<div id="navbar" class="navbar-collapse collapse">
  <ul class="nav navbar-nav custom_nav">
    <li class=""><a href="<%= Page.ResolveUrl(" ~/Home.aspx ") %>">Home</a>
    </li>
    <li class="dropdown"><a href="#" class="" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-expanded="false">Risk Context</a>
      <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
        <li><a href="<%= Page.ResolveUrl(" ~/pages/RiskContext/ObjectiveKPI.aspx ") %>">Objective (KPI)</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="<%= Page.ResolveUrl(" ~/pages/RiskContext/RiskLimitAndERR.aspx ") %>">Risk Limit & Expected Residual Risk</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="<%= Page.ResolveUrl(" ~/pages/RiskContext/ImpactScaleTables.aspx ") %>">Impact Scale Tables</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="<%= Page.ResolveUrl(" ~/pages/RiskContext/ProbabiityScaleTables.aspx ") %>">Probability Scale Tables</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="<%= Page.ResolveUrl(" ~/pages/Setting/SettingRole.aspx ") %>">Settings</a>
    </li>
    <ul>
</div>
```

What I miss from my code?? help me. thank before..

Comment: you must add css,JavaScript files in your page couse convert <li> to dropDownList

Comment: yess. its work. just false with my javascript jquery, bootsrap.js @AhmedGalal